# R: create new columns, base on rows and column combination

Tags: r

I am sure this could be simple, but I can't find a solution.. I have a series of buffers for multiple years. In each buffer, I record the extent of forest cover. The forest cover declines over years. In each buffer, I have also a type of management.

I want to add two new columns to my dataset:
the one regarding the original forest extent from 2003 for management type 0 and 1. The second relating the rate of forest extent to the original one, from 2003, for two types of management.

Based on these answers, I would assume to use something like: 
[R: fill new columns in data.frame based on row values by condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062476/r-fill-new-columns-in-data-frame-based-on-row-values-by-condition)

```
df$area2003<-with(df, area[year == 2003 & manag == 0][match(buff, buff[year== 2003 & manag == 0])])
```

but it does not work how expected.

My example:

```
# create data frame
buff<-c(c(rep(c(1:2), each = 2)), 
            c(rep(c(1:2), each = 2)))
area<-seq(800, 1, by = -100) 
year<-rep(2003:2004, each = 4)
manag<-rep(0:1, 4)

# create data frame
df<-data.frame(buff, area, year, manag)

# create values for original forest extent - how to code this???
df$area2003<-with(df, area[year == 2003 & manag == 0][match(distance, distance[year== 2003 & manag == 0])])
df$area2003<-with(df, area[year == 2003 & manag ==1 ][match(distance, distance[year== 2003 & manag == 1])])

# calculate forest rate:
df$rate<-df$area * 100/ df$area2003
```

What I expect to obtain:

```
  buff area year manag area2003   rate
1    1  800 2003     0      800 100.00
2    1  700 2003     1      700 100.00
3    2  600 2003     0      600 100.00
4    2  500 2003     1      500 100.00
5    1  400 2004     0      800  50.00
6    1  300 2004     1      700  42.86
7    2  200 2004     0      600  33.34
8    2  100 2004     1      500  20.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, since you aren't trying to update existing variables, you probably would do better to use a good-old fashioned `merge`.

```
dfNew <- merge(df, setNames(df[df$year == 2003, c("buff",  "manag", "area")],
                            c("buff",  "manag", "area2003")),
               by=c("buff",  "manag"))

# calculate change
dfNew$rate <- with(dfNew, 1 - abs(area - area2003) / area2003) * 100
```

which returns

```
dfNew
  buff manag area year area2003      rate
1    1     0  800 2003      800 100.00000
2    1     0  400 2004      800  50.00000
3    1     1  700 2003      700 100.00000
4    1     1  300 2004      700  42.85714
5    2     0  600 2003      600 100.00000
6    2     0  200 2004      600  33.33333
7    2     1  500 2003      500 100.00000
8    2     1  100 2004      500  20.00000
```

In the first line, I combined a number of steps, subsetting the data frame to 2003 and the columns of interest andrenaming the variables and in this subset data.frame with `setNames`.

To order the data.frame as you have it, use

```
dfNew <- dfNew[with(dfNew, order(year, buff, manag)), ]
```

The merge could be extended to additional lines. For example,

```
dfNew <- merge(df, df[df$year == 2003, c("buff",  "manag", "area")],
               by=c("buff",  "manag"))

names(dfNew) <- c("buff",  "manag", "area", "year", "area2003")
```

Answer (score 1):

Window functions of `dplyr` (`tidyverse`) are best suited to that kind of transformations. More examples in [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html).

```
library(tidyverse)

data_frame(
    buff = rep(1:2, 2, each = 2),
    area = 8:1*100,
    year = rep(2003:2004, each = 4),
    manag = rep(0:1, 4)
    ) %>%
    group_by(buff, manag) %>%
    arrange(year) %>%
    mutate(area2003 = first(area), rate = area/area2003*100)
```

Comment: nice! thank you, I'll need to dive deeper in dplyr ;))